# How to simplify complex creations with FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

In my app, I have this kind of structure:

```
Organization
  -- members (through many to many table)
  -- projects
    -- boards
      -- cards
        -- owner (user that must be a member of organization)
```

A lot of testing happens around cards, so I end up with too hairy setup methods, since `card` has to have `organization`, `project`, `board` and its owner.

How would you go about implementing a decent factory for `card` in this case?

**Current solution I'd like to clean up**:

Note I am missing the `board` connection to project, a board has columns and ideally the card should be dropped onto one of the columns.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :card do
    _project = FactoryGirl.create(:project)
    project _project
    subject { Faker::Hacker.say_something_smart }
    author _project.organization.members.first
  end

  factory :user do
    first_name { Faker::Name.first_name }
    last_name { Faker::Name.last_name }
    email { Faker::Internet.email }
    password 'mypassword'
    password_confirmation 'mypassword'
  end

  factory :project do
    name Faker::Internet.domain_name
    organization
  end

  factory :organization do
    name Faker::Company.name

    after(:create) do |post|
      2.times {
        post.members << FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      }
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: I usually do it with traits. `create :project, :with_boards` or something, where `:with_boards` trait will add some boards to the project.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am looking for a full blown example to help out myself, and possibly others, if you want to expand on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this structure

```
FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :project
 end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :organization do
 end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :board
   project
  end
 end

FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :owner do
  organization
 end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :card do
  board
  owner
  transient do
   owner_organization false
  end

  after(:create) do |card, evaluator|
   card.owner.update_attributes(organization: evaluator.organization) if evaluator.organization
  end
 end
end
```

Then you can try the follow approachs

- Default values of Project, Board and Owner `FacctoryGirl.create(:card)`
- Customized values with transient attributes `FactoryGirl.create(:card, owner_organization: Organization.last)`
- Customized values `FactoryGirl.create(:card, board: FactoryGirl.create(:board, project: FactoryGirl.create(:project)))`y

Comment: Thanks, you're missing organization and the user has to be part of it. I am trying to get rid of the second approach where I spell out everything.

Comment: Hi @hakunin, I have updated the answered, also added transient attributes in case you prefer a shortcut for updating associations.

Comment: Thanks, still - as I tried to point out - a board has to belong to a project thats part of the organization and the owner has to be a member of the organization. Thats where it gets a bit hairy. I'll post my current workaround so you can see the hairy bits.